# How to make this slider control to work in both directions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a range slider but it's working in single direction(to right) only and dragging out of parent container(#volume). How can I fix this?

I've attached a demo fiddle link.

Markup

```
<div id="volume">
    <div class="progress">
        <div class="volumeslider"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#volume{
    width:300px;
    background: #ddd;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.progress{
    height:10px;
    background:#999;
    position:relative;
    width:0;
}
.volumeslider {
    background: #808080;
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    right: -10px;
    top: -5px;
}
```

JS

```
$('.volumeslider').bind('mousedown', function(e){
    $('.volumeslider').bind('mousemove', function(e){
        $('.progress').width(e.pageX - $('.progress').offset().left + 'px');
        $(this).css('left', e.pageX - ($(this).width()/2) );
    });
    $('.volumeslider').bind('mouseup',function(){
        $('.volumeslider').unbind('mousemove');
    });
});
```

JS Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/2mYm7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of how to make it work always and everywhere. Right now it will stay dragging forever if you leave the element.

It includes border checks and makes sure the body is large enough so it stops dragging wherever on the page.

http://jsfiddle.net/2mYm7/5/

```
var dragging = null;

function startDrag(){
    console.log('started dragging', this);
    var $this = $(this);
    dragging = $this;
    $(document.body).bind('mouseup', stopDrag);
    $(document.body).bind('mousemove', drag);
}

function stopDrag(){
    console.log('stopped dragging', dragging[0]);
    $(document.body).unbind('mouseup', stopDrag);
    $(document.body).unbind('mousemove', drag);
    dragging = null;
}

function drag(e){
    var slider = dragging;
    var progress = slider.parent();
    var container = progress.parent();
    var maxOffset = container.width();
    progress.width(Math.min(e.pageX - progress.offset().left, maxOffset) + 'px');
}

$('.volumeslider').bind('mousedown', startDrag);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is exactly what I was trying to achieve. Upvoted. :)

Answer (score 2):

You have not taken into consideration the padding you have given to the body element.
I have made some changes to the code.

```
  $('.volumeslider').bind('mousedown', function (e) {
      console.log('binded');
    $('.volumeslider').bind('mouseup', function (e) {
        console.log('unbinded');
       $('.volumeslider').unbind('mousemove');
    });
    $('.volumeslider').bind('mousemove', function (e) {
      console.log('mousemove');
      $('.progress').width(e.pageX -  $('.progress').offset().left + 'px');
      $(this).css('left', e.pageX - 25- $(this).width());
    });

 });
```

Check this jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2mYm7/1/

Comment: You can remove the console statements once your debugging is done.
And also for what purpose you are using this slider? You have jquery-ui slider as well. With well defined functions http://jqueryui.com/slider/